# The word 'granulocytes' divides into three categories as 'neutrophils, eosinophils and basophils.' How may I include it in the following set-up?

Tags: arrays

The subdivision of `granulocytes` must be in the same figure; just as `luekocytes` were subdivided with curly brackets, `granulocytes' must be divided, but in the same figure.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
    \usepackage{array}
    \begin{document}
\[\text{Luekocytes}=\left\{\begin{array}{l l}
\text{Granulocytes}\\
\text{Agranulocytes}\\
\end{array}\right.\]\\
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for "cases" environment and "\text" macro
\begin{document}
\[
\text{Leukocytes}=
\begin{cases}
  \text{Granulocytes}
      \begin{cases}
        \text{Neutrophils}\\
        \text{Eosinophils}\\
        \text{Basophils}
      \end{cases}\\
   \text{Agranulocytes}\\
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you want a more compact "look", you could use nested `array` environments instead of nested `cases` environments. (Speaking for myself, I prefer the look that's produced with the `cases` environments.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\begin{document}
\[
\text{Leukocytes}= 
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
   \text{Granulocytes}
     \left\{ \begin{array}{l} 
        \text{Neutrophils}\\
        \text{Eosinophils}\\
        \text{Basophils}
     \end{array} \right.\\
   \text{Agranulocytes}\\
\end{array} \right.
\]
\end{document}
```